# How to set refresh and access token format used?

Tags: openiddict

I am refactoring an old codebase from OpenIddict 2 to version 4. One of the pieces of code I am having a hard time migrating comes from an old configuration that allowed setting the formats for refresh and access tokens:

```
services
    .AddOpenIddict()
    .AddServer(options =>
    {
        options.Configure(
            o =>
            {
                o.RefreshTokenFormat = new JWTRefreshTokenFormat(
                    tokenKey,
                    OrbitConfiguration.SystemHostname,
                    OrbitConfiguration.AlternativeSystemHostname);
                o.AccessTokenFormat = new JWTAccessTokenFormat(
                    tokenKey,
                    OrbitConfiguration.SystemHostname,
                    OrbitConfiguration.AlternativeSystemHostname);
            });
    }
```

The code above allowed us to set custom implementations of  `ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>` for both the refresh and access token. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find an alternative for it as I am migrating to version 4 of Openiddict.

I tried looking at the code in github, also checked the git history to see if I could find when or why this got removed, but failed to find it since this was an old code from an archived library.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing in recent versions of OpenIddict. Instead, you need to create custom `IOpenIddictServerHandler<GenerateTokenContext>` and `IOpenIddictServerHandler<ValidateTokenContext>` event handlers.

See https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/tree/dev/src/OpenIddict.Server.DataProtection for a concrete example using ASP.NET Core Data Protection as the token format.